# Is there man page making software?

Tags: macos, manpage

I was wondering if anyone knew of any `manpage` making software? I have looked at the OSX manpages and dissected them, but I'm looking at something that will easily convert from a txt file to a manpage for me, much like Octopress converts from `.markdown` to `.html` for me. I'd prefer something that runs on OSX. Even an app that generates them on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manpages [are processed with troff](http://liw.fi/manpages), a typesetting system comparable to TeX.

Comment: Searched for so long. Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!